# create nested arrays from PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create nested arrays here where there is an array that contains each **$forum_topic_name**, and then within that array, I need to list each associated **$subtopic_name**

```
$find_forum_topics = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM forumTopics ORDER BY listValue ASC");

while ($find_forum_topics_row = mysqli_fetch_array($find_forum_topics)) {
    $forum_topic_name[] = $find_forum_topics_row['topicName'];

    $find_forum_subtopics = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, subTopicName FROM forumSubTopics WHERE topicID='$forum_topic_id' ORDER BY listValue ASC");

    while ($find_forum_subtopics_row = mysqli_fetch_array($find_forum_subtopics)) {
        $subtopic_name[] = $find_forum_subtopics_row['subTopicName']; 
    }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to encode it as JSON so I can display the following:

```
<div class="topic">
    <div class="topicname">Topic 1</div>
    <div class="subtopics">
        <div class="subtopicname">Subtopic 1</div>
        <div class="subtopicname">Subtopic 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="topic">
    <div class="topicname">Topic 2</div>
    <div class="subtopics">
        <div class="subtopicname">Subtopic 1</div>
        <div class="subtopicname">Subtopic 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

there are can be several options, but you can go with:

```
$find_forum_topics = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM forumTopics ORDER BY listValue ASC");

while ($find_forum_topics_row = mysqli_fetch_array($find_forum_topics)) {
    $topicName = $find_forum_topics_row['topicName']; // get topic name
    $forum_topic_name[$topicName] = array(); // use it as key to array

    $find_forum_subtopics = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, subTopicName FROM forumSubTopics WHERE topicID='$forum_topic_id' ORDER BY listValue ASC");

    while ($find_forum_subtopics_row = mysqli_fetch_array($find_forum_subtopics)) {
        $forum_topic_name[$topicName][] = $find_forum_subtopics_row['subTopicName']; // add sub topics
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...now how do I get this into an array that I can encode into JSON?

Comment: So, it's returning this: {"Topic 1":[],"Topic 2":[],"Topic 3":[],"Topic 4":[],"Topic 5":[],"Topic 6":[]} --- but the subtopics aren't there as nested arrays

Comment: @Danw right, because you do not have subtopics, where topicID is empty string, as you do not init `topicID='$forum_topic_id'`